# Best practice for adding firewall exception: program or port exception?

Tags: wcf-security, windows-firewall

For a distributed production client-server WCF application (self-hosted as a Windows Service with NetTcpBinding), I am adding logic to add expception to Windows Firewall during the installation via netsh command.

I have noticed that the remote communication seems to work fine whether the firewall exception is for the program (the executable) or port.  In our case, the port will very rarely be something other than the default and if it is then user can manually alter config files and firewall accordingly.

My question is, whether it is better to add the exception for **program OR port OR both**.  Are there any security considerations making one approach more desirable than the other?  Virtually all of the examples for WCF show port exceptions.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: in my case (particularly for the server end, using HTTP binding) merely adding exception for the "program" is not enough, therefore not adding exception for the port is not an option... but the fact that i can't unblock a port to be used specifically by http.sys or whatever program is responsible for initiating the background communication for my configuration, bothers me a bit... :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is my summary of how I think they function:

Application exception **-->** grants the specified application to open any ports

Port exception **-->** grants any application to open the specified port

As such, which one is better suited depends on the situation.  Generally, the application exception would be preferred.  At the time an application attempts to open a port, the Windows Firewall (if enabled) essentially would do a check to determine if that application or the port itself has been granted an exception.

MSDN states: *"[Application exception] is more secure than opening a port, because the firewall is only open while the program is waiting to receive the connection."*

More detailed MSDN summary and technical articles: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545423.aspx

Ultimately, the system admin for the deployed software should be aware of and/or be the one who makes the changes to the firewall.  What we plan on doing is having a step in the installer where the customer can opt-out of the firewall exception but explaining that remote clients will not be able to communicate without it.  And of course the manual documentation will also outline the required ports for scenarios if other software or hardware firewalls are in place and need to be manually configured.